# My Queue and Stack are getting merged and generating a very peculiar bug

Tags: data-structures, queue, stack

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Doc
{
    int id;
    char name[50];
    struct Doc *next;
}doc;

typedef struct Queue
{
    doc *front;
    doc *rear;
}queue;

doc *stack_top = NULL;


void initiate(queue *q)
{
    q->front = NULL;
    q->rear = NULL;
}

void enqueue(queue *q)
{
    system("cls");
    doc *temp;
    temp = (doc*)malloc(sizeof(doc));

    printf("Enter doc ID: ");
    scanf("%d%*c", &temp->id);
    printf("Enter doc name: ");
    char name[50];
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", name);
    strcpy(temp->name, name);
    temp->next = NULL;

    if(q->front == NULL && q->rear == NULL)
    {
        q->front = q->rear = temp;
        printf("Doc number %d has been saved successfully!\n", q->rear->id);
        system("pause");
        return;
    }
    q->rear->next = temp;
    q->rear = temp;

    printf("Doc number %d has been saved successfully!\n", q->rear->id);
    system("pause");
}

doc* dequeue(queue *q)
{
    if(q->front == NULL)
    {
        printf("Queue is empty!\n");
        system("pause");
        return NULL; ///code is not working with -1 return value.
    }

    doc *temp;
    temp = q->front;
    q->front = temp->next;
    temp->next = NULL;

    return temp;
}

void view_r_bin(void)
{
    system("cls");
    doc *head;
    head = stack_top;

    printf("\t\tRecycle Bin\n");
    printf("------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Doc ID \t Doc Name\n");
    while(head != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d \t %s\n", head->id, head->name);
        head = head->next;
    }
    system("pause");
}

void menu(void)
{
    system("cls");
    printf("\tMenu\n");
    printf("---------------------\n");
    printf("1. Add a document\n"); ///ok
    printf("2. Get a document\n");
    printf("3. View the recycle bin\n");
    printf("4. Restore 1 document from recycle bin\n");
    printf("5. How many Documents are there in the queue?\n");
    printf("6. How many Documents are there in the recycle bin?\n");
    printf("0. Exit\n");
    printf("\n\nEnter your choice: ");
}

int main(void)
{
    doc *temp;
    queue *q;
    q = (queue*)malloc(sizeof(queue));
    initiate(q);
    int ch;
    while(1)
    {
        menu();
        scanf("%d", &ch);

        switch(ch)
        {
        case 1:
            enqueue(q);
            break;
        case 2:
            system("cls");
            printf("Book ID \t Book Name\n");
            printf("------------------------------------\n");
            temp = dequeue(q);
            if(temp != NULL)
            {
                printf("Doc ID: %d \t Doc Name: %s\n",temp->id, temp->name);
                system("pause");
                temp->next = stack_top;
                stack_top = temp;
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            view_r_bin();
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        case 5:
            break;
        case 6:
            break;
        case 0:
            free(q);
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

after running the code, every thing is fine. Let's say I enqueue 3 docs. then performed 3 dequeue. the dequeued data will be stored in a stack. if I dequeue 4th time it shows my queue is empty. and that is totally fine. But now comes the bug. After finishing dequeue all elements, when I enqueue again, the doc data is not going to the queue. Instead it is deleting all element of the stack below the top doc, getting added under the top. And now each time I enqueue a data, it is continuously getting added in the stack like a queue and my main queue is always empty. please help me to solve this bug.

I want to develop a mini project of Doc management system usung stack + queue. All docs will be stored in a queue. if I delete a doc or dequeue a doc, it goes to the recycle bin (stack). So, that I can restore my data whenever I want.

Comment: No one is going to have the time to read through all of this code to find the bug(s). Please reduce it to a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: For example, it looks like your primarily problem is enqueuing after dequeuing. That implies that the problem is that dequeuing the entire structure does not leave it in the same state it started with. When you enqueue, you set both `front` and `rear` pointers, but when you dequeue, you only set the `front` pointer. What if `front` is now `NULL`? Should you set `rear` to `NULL` as well?